# IOS - Back icon + 'back' label vs back icon only

Tags: navigation, ios, back-button

I'm working on an iPhone app and we are currently designing the navigation.

I'm wondering what would be the best option (and why) when it comes to going back to the previous page.

1. Back icon + 'back' label
2. Back icon only

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **icon + text** when the back icon is on the top navbar. Here's why:

- iOS uses the **<** symbol for *Back*. This takes very less real estate so having text makes sense
- It may get missed when used on the top-left corner of the screen

[image: iOS back icon with text]

The only scenario where you could use **icon without text** is when you are using it as browser actions like so

[image: iOS browser action set]

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I do agree that we should have the back icon + 'back' label if we follow Apple guidelines but I'm more questioning the impact on the UX!

Comment: Having the text increases the **touch radius** which is great for accessibility. So UX-wise also, that's a better solution

Comment: That's a very good point. Cheers.